# WebSocket - Идентификация. Механизм распределения

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, websocket

Начал изучать протокол `WS` и стало не понятно...

```
var clients = {};

var ws = new WebSocketServer.Server({
    port: 3000
});


ws.on('connection', function(ws) {
    var id = random(1, 100) // min, - max
    clients[id] = ws;
});

# ...
```

как вы видите, при создании соединения, для каждого юзера, в массив добавляется  объект соединения... получается, если я хочу отправить определенному пользователю сообщение, я беру этот объект и делаю `send`? а как же тогда, если пользователь перейдет на другую страницу сайта? (если перейдет, то соединение срывается и устанавливается новое, с новым объектом...) будет ли этот объект активным, чтобы я мог оповещать его где бы он не находился?

где-то читал, что соединения достаточно хранить в памяти сервера, то есть в переменной `clients`. то есть:

```
var clients = {
    questions: {
        324: <ws_object>
    }
}
```

в `questions` есть идентификаторы вопросов (324...etc), туда добавляются те юзеры, которые подписаны на этот вопрос... опять появляется проблема с новым соединением, придется строить костыли и добавлять активные соединения... а что если сервер аварийно завершиться? вся структура полетит к черту

получается, эти объекты соединения  нужно хранить в `БД`? если я хочу оповестить юзера, я беру из `БД` (по его `id`) этот объект и отправляю данные?

прошу объяснить, как это все происходит; механизм идентификации и управление пользователями. спасибо!

Comment: Что за метка [tag:ue]?

Comment: опечатка, исправил

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgcBPjdr2fs&index=42&list=PLDyvV36pndZFWfEQpNixIHVvp191Hb3Gg

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket - это аналог обычного сокета, разработанный специально для случая когда в качестве клиента выступает браузер. Тем не менее WebSocket-ы можно использовать не только в связке с браузером. Но особого смысла в этом не будет, правильнее будет использовать обычные сокеты. В общем случае для использования протокола WebSocket - и клиент и сервер обязаны поддерживать этот протокол. Современные браузеры из коробки поддерживают WebSocket, поэтому если в качестве клиента выступает современный браузер - пол дела уже сделано. Осталось обеспечить поддержку WebSocket на стороне сервера.

Взаимодействие двух узлов (клиент и сервер) с помощью сокетов (WebSocket) - это создание постоянного соединения с двусторонней передачей данных (двусторонний канал передачи данных). Для этого на каждом узле создается по своему экземпляру сокета. После этого каждый из узлов может принимать и передавать данные по установленному каналу. Важно понимать что каналу соответствует пара сокетов - один на одном узле (клиент), второй на другом узле (сервер). В данном контексте соединение инициирует именно клиент, и никак иначе. То-есть сервер ожидает новые соединения и обрабатывает их, но инициатором всегда выступает клиент. После создания канала, данные можно посылать в каком угодно порядке, и тут все зависит только от фантазии разработчика.

Экземпляр WebSocket на стороне клиента имеет время жизни не более чем время жизни страницы, то-есть с закрытием страницы соединение будет разорвано и клиентский экземпляр WebSocket уничтожен. Это означает что соответствующий ему серверный экземпляр не имеет более пары и посылать/принимать по нему данные более не получится. Сервер должен отслеживать разрыв соединения и удалять такие сокеты.

*С теорией разобрались, советы касательно вопроса.*
В базе данных нужно хранить данные, которые при необходимости передавать посредством сокетов на клиент. С использованием современных технологий на подобии протокола WebSocket стоит переходить на новые стандарты разработки веб-сайтов. Имеет смысл смотреть в сторону одностраничных сайтов. В таком случае при переходе на сайт будет открыта единственная страница и будет создан в общем случае единственный экземпляр WebSocket. Конечно и на клиенте нужно предусмотреть обработку исключительных ситуаций. Ведь соединение может быть разорвано без инициативы сервера. Клиент при необходимости может повторно создать соединение.

> будет ли этот объект активным, чтобы я мог оповещать его где бы он не находился?

Выше уже дан ответ, перефразирую. Нет, серверный объект не будет активен и подлежит ручному уничтожению. Клиент должен сам 
позаботиться, и создать новый канал. Важно предусмотреть механизм идентификации - сервер должен как-то различать клиентов между собой. Хотя в общем случае это и не обязательно.

> механизм идентификации и управление пользователями

Никак не происходит, точнее происходит так как того пожелает разработчик. Нужно уяснить простую вещь - WebSockets - это всего лишь механизм для двусторонней передачи данных по сети. Также нужно понимать что эта самая передача данных основывается на постоянном соединении. То-есть два узла связаны постоянным соединением и каждый из них может передавать когда угодно и какие угодно данные. В простом случае можно ограничиться текстовыми данными, но WebSockets также поддерживают и двоичные данные. Собственно это все что необходимо знать для начала. Далее же безотносительно использования WebSockets необходимо предусмотреть протокол передачи данных. Протокол можно построить на сообщениях.

Пример клиентского сообщения, для авторизации:

```
{type: "auth", login: "user", pass: "password"}
```

Пример ответа сервера:

```
{type: "auth", status: false}
```

Тоесть гость подключился к серверу и является таковым до тех пор пока не отправит авторизационое сообщение с правильными данными, которые сервер проверит и переведет гостя в авторизированного юзера. Для вышесказанного еще надо предусмотреть процедуру регистрации - именно для создания новых пользователей.

Это очень обширная тема, и на нее можно написать книгу. Озвучу  некоторые моменты. Клиент (и сервер) в этом контексте выступают как машина состояний, и только разработчику решать какая будет реализована логика. Изначально пользователь попадает на сайт неавторизированным. Ему может быть доступна часть функционала, а может и нет. Сервер же обязан хранить состояние каждого клиента. Часть состояния - как соединение (WebSocket), статус авторизации можно хранить только в памяти сервера, не более, кроме того WebSocket ну никак не сохранишь в БД, да и не имеет это смысла. А всю остальную информацию о состоянии пользователей необходимо хранить, например, в БД. После перезагрузки сервера (аварийного завершения) эти данные будут вновь доступны.

Относительно кода: Ваш пример очень простой и не отражает истинного положения дел. Для работы с пользователями сервер обязан их различать. По простому нужно создать класс User со всеми необходимыми данными, его же и сохранять в БД. А при определенных условиях (успешная авторизация) связывать текущее соединение с этим пользователем.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что это не `PHP`. То есть, `PHP` - это скриптовый язык, он выполнятся и сразу завершается. И все! Для каааждого соединения создается новый процесс,- код заново выполняется. `NodeJS` - это поточный сервер, который **работает постоянно**(!), в одном процессе. Соответственно, ему доступно одно и тоже пространство памяти

Что касается Вашего вопроса:
То это просто! Если Вы хотите хранить объекты соединения в `БД`, то знайте, что будут проблемы с  сериализацией этого объекта.. Это плохая идея и так делать не нужно. 
Объектам достаточно присваивать идентификационные номера, чтобы их различать:

У зарегистрированных пользователей есть свой некий `id`, поэтому значению и введется механизм управления.

*При открытии нового соединения, обновляйте объект соединения, с идентификатором пользователя*

---

> в questions есть идентификаторы вопросов (324...etc), туда добавляются те юзеры, которые подписаны на этот вопрос...

```
var clients = {
    questions: {
        324: <ws_object>
    }
}
```

Это неправильно. Саму логику нужно хранить в `БД`(или в каком-нибудь хранилище). Ибо если скрипт завершиться вы потеряете ваши сохраненные подписки на вопросы.

Создайте отдельную таблицу в БД, там добавляйте: кто на что подписан. Например:

```
qid | uid
324 |  54
```

Пользователь с идентификатором `54` подписан на вопрос с идентификатором `324`

При появлении нового события, рассылайте оповещения исходя из этой таблицы

Answer (score -2):

вот https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets довольно полное описание. к @sba следует добавить , что в websocket есть механизм отслеживания обрыва или отключения соединения. при перходе на новую страницу коннект ws будет новым, но имя юзера останется прежним, вот по этому имени и надо выбирать коннект ws для отправки сообщения нужному юзеру.

Comment: >"но имя юзера останется прежним" 
непонятно, какое имя Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: когда юзер авторизируется на сайте с помощью логина пароля - на всё время сессии иго логин/имя остаются постоянными при переходе по страницам сайта. поэтому при переходе на новую страницу надо привязывать логин к коннекту ws.

Comment: интересно какой трус втихушку заминусовал? или дурак?